# ST_Distance_Spheroid returning very large value

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have hard coded here one of the coordinates. In reality, the distance in km between these two points is around 2.2 km but the query returns 8033830.232829098 which as suggested by the PostGIS documentation should represent the distance in meters => 8033 km is a lot larger.

```
select ST_DistanceSpheroid(
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
                '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[53.4623013676122,-2.25182451244364]}'
            ),
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
                (
                    select
                        coordinates::text
                    from
                        actor
                    where
                        actor.id = '4b9722c0-50dd-11e7-b8e3-4d48263ab9fd'
                )
            ),
            'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
        )
```

What do I miss ? I have checked various threads online and the query seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the code has been changed and by mistake, the long and lat coordinates have been saved in the different order inside the database. It is important that for ST_Distance_Spheroid we should provide the coordinates in [lon, lat] order.